# How can I toggle a div and load content into div during open state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to toggle a div open, load a page into that div, then be able to toggle it closed.

I want to do this with multiple links.

```
<div id="main-nav">
            <div id="menu-container">
            <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html"></a></li>
                <li id="clicklink"><a href="#">mission</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">leadership</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">awards</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sustainability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">faq</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="clickme3">
                <img src="images/logo-sm.png">
            </div>

            </div>
            <div id="content-load">

            </div>
    </div>

$("#clicklink").toggle(function () {
    $("#main-nav").animate({
        height: "300",
    }, 1000, function () {
        $("#content-load").load("contentpage.html", function () {

        })
        function () {
            $("#main-nav").animate({
                height: "40",
            }, 1000, )
        };
    });
});
```

This is what I have that isn't working.

I can get this to work, but of course does not toggle.

```
$("#clicklink").click(function () {
    $("#main-nav").animate({
        height: "300",
    }, 1000, function () {
        $("#content-load").load("contentpage.html", function () {

        })
    });
});
```

I'm new to jQuery but eager to learn. Is there a way that I can get this to toggle?

```
You can view production here http://billygoforth/learning/CMD
```

You can see that it shifts the bottom navigation up (which is what I want) and loads the external page content below (also what I want), but I want to have it so if the link is clicked again, it collapses and then I can put this jquery on the other link IDs.

Again, many thanks!

Comment: Check console for errors and make fiddle.

Comment: Yes please provide us a fiddle so we see your CSS and HTML as well

Comment: It's not clear at which point you want to do what. 1. When you want to close it? What you mean by *"multiple links"*?

Comment: Not familiar with Fiddle. I added HTML and link to production site. Again, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
// global variable 
var toggleHeight = $('#main-nav').height();
$("#clicklink").click(function () {
    if(toggleHeight <= 0){
       $("#main-nav").animate({
           height: "300px",
       }, 1000, function () {
           $("#content-load").load("contentpage.html");
       });
    }
    else{
       $("#main-nav").animate({
           height: "0px",
       }, 1000, function () { });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it just made the bar shrink and disappear. I want it to push the bottom navigation up and load content from external page underneath. You can see the site here http://billygoforth.com/learning/CMD and I added the markup above. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve this:

The plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/PcE2hxY4q98Trw90ztnL?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div class="view" data-page="contentPage.html">
  <div class="actions">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Toggle View</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="view" data-page="other.html">
  <div class="actions">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Toggle View</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $(".view").each(function(){
    var page = $(this).data("page")
    $(this).find(".content").load(page, function(){
        $(this).animate({height: 40});
      });
  })
  $(".actions input").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).parent().parent().siblings(".content").animate({height: 300});
    }else
   {
      $(this).parent().parent().siblings(".content").animate({height: 40});
    }
  });
});
```